# Do animals repopulate?

Tags: rimworld

After killing a bunch of animals for leather and meat, there are noticably fewer on the map. Will their numbers increase over time, or in an event (aside from the alphabeaver invasion), or are they a finite resource?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, I think they wander on from the side of the map. In some areas - ones that get snowy during winter - all animals on the map will disappear (somehow) and return again in the spring.